# Load HTML5 webview into an app

Tags: kindle, kindle-kdk

I have no experience with the Kindle KDK, so maybe this is a dull question. I'm wondering. Is it possible to create a simple app that loads a webview? So we could easily "wrap" an existing product.

If so, I'm interested in the possibilities:

- what engine does it use currently (like WebKit)
- does it have HTML5 capabilities like Web Storage and Application Cache
- how good is JavaScript perfomance

I've found on Wikipedia that it uses "[[…] an experimental WebKit based browser […]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#Ports)", but what is it capable of doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the KDK doesn't give access to a Webview (like Android or iOS), so you can't load any web page content, or use any HTML 5 capabilities. The WebKit browser is just the built-in browser for surfing the Web.